# Youtube API list with videos, android

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

How can i have a list of videos play like playlist? 
I have a string of videoID not playlistID which acts like playlist, that is video play one after other, next video button to display on youtubeplayer.

```
private static final String1[] arry = { 
          new String1("Androidify App", "irH3OSOskcE", false),
          new String1("Chrome Speed Tests", "nCgQDjiotG0", false),
          new String1("Playlist: Google I/O 2012", "PL56D792A831D0C362", true)};
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use **onVideoEnded()** method of **YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener** interface to play it one by one.

Have a look here
[YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener)

Comment: thanks but will that work for videoID? not playlist?

Comment: yes exactly , it'll work for videoId.
when your video ends , this method gets called automatically
and in that method you just put your own logic for playing next video.
and feel free for +1. :)

Comment: thanks, that helps. but how can i get that next button on youtube player itself? like the way we see in playlist. When that button is pressed next video plays.

Comment: Hey. for this you can have your own button in android. that's very easy to put. Isn't it.

Comment: hey i'm using following https://code.google.com/p/youtube-api-samples/source/browse/android-player/src/com/examples/youtubeapidemo/PlayerControlsDemoActivity.java?r=2ea6cc01ecb4d9691ef9f8beec2398476233de5a not exactly sure what should  call in onVideoEnded() to switch next video from array.